# Is this "weakened form of uniform convergence" sufficient here?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

I'm looking at an infinite series of continuous functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, say $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)$, which converges pointwise to a function $f(x)$. Let $S_n$ be the n-th partial sum of the series.

If we assume that all $f_k$ are differentiable, I want the equation

$\frac{d}{dx} (\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k'(x)$

to be true for all $x$. Now we know that this is true, if $S'_n$ converges uniformly to $f'$. But what happens if we only have a weaker condition for $S'_n$:

For every $\epsilon>0$ there is *a number* $n$ such that $|f'-S'_n|<\epsilon$ holds for all $x$.

I highly appreciate your help and thoughts.

Comment: It isn't true that uniform convergence of $S_n$ implies convergence of $S_n'$. The other way around is true: uniform convergence of $S_n'$ and convergence of $S_n(x_0)$ at a single point imply uniform convergence of $S_n$ on compact intervals plus that $S'=\lim_n S_n'$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will correct my question. Thx!

Comment: it means that there is a subsequence of the $S_n'$ that converges to $f$ as you can pick it more or less as $n_k$ for $\epsilon = \frac{1}{k}$ (you have to be a little careful and use an inductive process to make sure $n_k$ increases but that's the idea).

Comment: NO. For any sequence, replace  $f_1$ with $f$  so $n=1$ for all $\epsilon>0.$

Comment: @Conrad: Thanks for the suggestions. Is ok that the subsequence $(S_{n_m})_m$ with $m\geq k$ is dependent on the particular choice of $\epsilon$? And I need to show that $(n_k)_k$ is monotonically increasing (at least, for all $k \geq k_0$) before I can assume the existence of such a subsequence (or?)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $n$ must get larger as  $\epsilon$ gets smaller. But that is not what is stated.

Comment: Unless there is a fixed $n$ for which $f'=S_n'$ - which indeed makes the assumptions on the derivative pointless, but imho the question implicitly excludes such as that is a trivially uninteresting and artificial case - you can always choose an increasing sequence of $n$ with lower $\epsilon$ by standard procedure

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: I'm not assuming it, I was hoping it can be proofed. But I don't see it yet.

Comment: What I should have said in my first comment was: Let$ f_1=f$ and let $\sum_{j=2}^n f_j$ converge point-wise to $0$ as $n\to \infty.$